# OpenSSL in C - routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number when trying to connect to server using TLS1_2

Tags: c, tcp, openssl, tls1.2

I am trying to make a "curl" client that can send requests to servers in C.
I've done creating a TCP socket (using slides from college, tested):

```
int connect_to_host(char * hostname, int port) {
  // AF_INET: create socket that uses IPv4; SOCK_STREAM: type of sequenced, reliable
  // 2-way connection-based byte streams ~ TCP (as opposed to datagrams ~ UDP)
  int socket_fd;
  struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
  struct hostent * hp;
  
  if ((socket_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
    return -1; // remember to broadcast error, saved in errno (extern int errno)
  }
  
  // geting address (contained in struct hostent) from DNS
  if ((hp = gethostbyname(hostname)) == NULL) {
    return -2; // can't find hostname from DNS
  }
  // per documentation, must zero out bytes in the 'server' socket address before filling values
  bzero((char *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
  // filling necessary values of the 'server' socket address
  server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; // using IPv4
  server_addr.sin_port = htons(port); // assign port value, remember to change int (host order byte)
                                      // to network order byte. htons = host-to-network-short (short int)
  bcopy((char *)hp->h_addr_list[0], (char *)&server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, hp->h_length); // IP address, got from DNS
  
  if (connect(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0) {
    return -1; // error, as above
  }
  return socket_fd;
}
```

And created a TLS-version-flexible SSL/TLS context:

```
SSL_CTX * init_CTX() {
  SSL_METHOD * method;
  SSL_CTX * ctx;
  OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms(); // Load cryptos, et.al.
  SSL_load_error_strings(); // Bring in and register error messages
  method = TLS_client_method(); // create new client-method instance
  if ((ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method)) == NULL) {; // create new context
    return NULL;
  }
  return ctx;
}
```

My next step is to create an SSL connection state and "bind" it with the file descriptor return by the TCP function (connect_to_host()) above. Then I will try to make SSL_connect()

```
if (*tls_mode == 1) {
  ctx = init_CTX();
  ssl = SSL_new(ctx); // create new SSL connection state
  SSL_set_fd(ssl, clientfd); // bind socket descriptor to ssl state
  if (SSL_connect(ssl) == -1) {
    printf("SSL connection failed\n");
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    return -1;
  }
  printf("debug tls: connect\n");
  if (show_cert) SSL_show_certs(ssl);
}
```

**At this point** I receive the error in the title. I have checked stackoverflow and places but I don't see questions using C and the OpenSSL library. If anyone can give me a hint, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: The kind of error you get is commonly seen when trying to do a SSL/TLS connection to a server which doesn't speak SSL/TLS in the first place.  So, what is the server you are trying to connect to and does it even speak SSL/TLS on the given port?

Comment: I was trying to connect to https:// www.google.com.
When I tried HTTP with http:// www.google.com (http not secured), everything goes well. So I guess the create socket part is working fine, and think the SSL/TLS might be the problem.

Comment: Oh thank you. After said so I checked my port variable and see that the port number is wrong. The issue is fixed now. Thank you for your help and sorry for this.

Answer (score 1):

So for anyone who checks back on this later, I made a mistake with my port number, and connect to port 80 instead of 443, causing the error.